# Sublime Text FormatLua Error

Tags: lua, format, runtime-error, sublimetext

I'm trying to format code with a package I installed for Sublime Text 3 - FormatLua.

However, I'm getting this error when I try to use it...

```
/usr/local/bin/lua: ./metalua/compiler.lua:119:
./metalua/compiler/bytecode/lopcodes.lua:284: attempt to call field
'gfind' (a nil value) stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ./metalua/compiler.lua:119: in function 'get_bytecode_compiler'
    ./metalua/compiler.lua:125: in function 'f'
    ./metalua/compiler.lua:153: in function <./metalua/compiler.lua:150>
    (...tail calls...)
    [C]: in function 'require'
    formatter.lua:24: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Does anyone know what I must do to fix this issue? I must be missing some files - I see that `gfind` is nil (this was taken out after 5.0), but I don't want to mess with anything unless I'm *sure* I know what I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `gfind` was deprecated. You can replace `string.gfind` with `string.gmatch`. I applied a similar change for the same reason; here is the [commit](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/commit/01b8eea47b7d7a28a28a9122ffc57bacac5d3293).

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find that file? Where's lualibs/metalua?

Comment: It's probably included in that FormatLua package; you'll need to check the content of the package.

Comment: Found it, and thus realised there are many errors in the treequery script that isn't even the correct language :| Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Works well after downgrading lua version to 5.1.4
Compiling from source code:
Lua 5.1.4 here: http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.4.tar.gz:

Open your Terminal.app

```
wget http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.4.tar.gz
tar xvzf lua-5.1.4.tar.gz
cd lua-5.1.4
make macosx
make install
```